# Java FXML: Putting a string variable into a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm writing an FXML application using JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0. I have a Text Area containing a couple paragraphs of text. I want to take a variable that the user inputs (in this case, a name), and put it into the first paragraph.

The name is contained in a text file. I have a class to read that name from the text file and store the name into a String variable in the Controller. How do I get that String variable from the Controller, to my FXML View, and put it in the TextArea?

So, it should end up as a window with a TextArea that says "Greetings, [NAME], and welcome to my application...etc..."

Comment: take a look at this Oracle tutorial - https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm

Comment: you will need a controller field for the name that uses the @FXML attribute - that will map to a corresponding field in your view that uses fx:id=

Comment: @choff It's close, but I need it to be put in an existing field with other text. Kind of like if I were writing a printf statement in C with a variable, I would write printf("My name is %s", stringName);

Comment: So for XML, I need something like <TextArea text="My name is %s, welcome to the app."> where %s is the name I bring in as a variable. Any ideas how that syntax would work?

Comment: @DannytheHopeless You could do basically exactly that, and then in the controller's `initialize()` method do `textField.setText(String.format(textField.getText(), username));`.  Give the text field a `fx:id`, etc, in the usual way.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys!